# SQL Server Stored Procedure Check if Record Exists Before Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am doing a check to see if a record exists before inserting it into a table (and this method seems to work on other stored procedures I am already using) but for this particular stored procedure it is not inserting anything even though the table is empty, why not?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertMovieHasTrailer
    @movieID int,
    @name varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @name = name, @movieID = movieID
    FROM MovieHasTrailer
    WHERE name = @name and movieID = @movieID

    IF @name IS NULL and @movieID IS NULL
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MovieHasTrailer
    (
        movieID,
        name
    )
    Values (
        @movieID,
        @name
    )
    END
END
```

Executing like this:

```
execute spInsertMovieHasTrailer 1, 'Test'
```

Comment: Try switching to a simple @@ROWCOUNT check (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

I would build this directly into the `insert` and not use `if` logic.  `if` introduces race conditions:

```
INSERT INTO MovieHasTrailer
    SELECT movieID, name
    FROM (SELECT @movieID as movieID, @name as name) t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM MovieHasTrailer mht
                      WHERE mht.MovieId = t.MovieID AND mht.name = t.name
                     );
```

Note that this assumes that you need both the id and name to match the movie.  I would think the `id` would be sufficient.

Also, what I would really do is have a unique index on either `MovieHasTrailer(MovieId)` or `MovieHasTrailer(MovieId, Name)`.  Then use a `try`/`catch` block if there is an insert error.

Answer (score 2):

your select into variable may returns more than one value and you get error, it's better to use `if not exists`:

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(
   SELECT name, movieID
   FROM MovieHasTrailer
   WHERE name = @name and movieID = @movieID
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO MovieHasTrailer
(
    movieID,
    name
)
Values (
    @movieID,
    @name
)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not doing an insert is the following code will not change the value of @name and @movieID if the query returns no records

```
SELECT @name = name, @movieID = movieID
FROM MovieHasTrailer
WHERE name = @name and movieID = @movieID
```

Whatever value for @name and @movieID you are passing into the stored procedure remain unchanged. I assume you are not passing in null values so the IF block is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also you can achieve your goal and it save your time also.

```
INSERT INTO MovieHasTrailer
      SELECT @movieID as movieID, @name as name
        except
      select MovieId, name
        FROM MovieHasTrailer mht
              where  MovieId = @MoveID
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by standart `MERGE` statement:

```
Create table t(id int, name nvarchar(max))
Declare @id int = 1, @name nvarchar(max) = 'Mission imposible'

Merge t using (select @id, @name) as s(id, name)
on t.id = s.id
when not matched then
insert(id, name) values(s.id, s.name);
```

You can also add `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE`, `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE` to this statement.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c2569/23

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertMovieHasTrailer
@movieID int,
@name varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
declare @rowStatus nvarchar(50)=null

set @rowStatus=(SELECT name FROM MovieHasTrailer WHERE name = @name and movieID = @movieID)

IF (@rowStatus is NULL)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO MovieHasTrailer
(
    movieID,
    name
)
Values (
    @movieID,
    @name
)
END
END
```